# I need to use a function to check if a uid already exists in the database before the user is created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm building an application, and I have everything set up and working properly. I did some modifications, using rand-token, to have shorter ID's for user profiles, comments, and posts.

I am able to put the randomly generated token into the new ID field (uid for users), but I'm stuck trying to figure out where to put a function to check whether or not the uid already exists in the database before passport writes to the database. I haven't tried to test it by putting a static string in where the random token is generated to see if mongo or passport automatically error out if two ID's exist.

So I guess this is a multi part question.

1) Where exactly could i put a function to check to see if a uid exists before writing to the db?

and

2) Does mongo or even passport do this automatically? I couldn't find documentation for this scenario.

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate post, I've looked at other similar posts but couldn't find anything that is similar to what I need.

Also its worth noting that I'm not talking about a username. I'm talking about uid, separate from username and _id.

Comment: I am not well acquainted to either MongoDb or Passport so I could be off the beaten track here but you could use Guids, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier. It is extremely, extremely unlikely to create duplicates and thus you wouldn't have to test for duplicates. You could also use indexes in MongoDb and last but not least, this might be an interesting read on your problem - if you want to check for a 'uid' manually - but potentially overkill, https://www.quora.com/How-do-giant-sites-like-Reddit-verify-that-a-username-isnt-taken-so-fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its solved. mongo errors out if multiple ids' exist